# jQuery auto-apply plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins

wrote a little jquery gallery plugin and i'm initializing like this: `myDiv.tGallery();`

my question: is it possible to have jQuery detect if the HTML markup contains gallery code (eg. defined by its classname .myPlugs_gallery) and auto-apply the plugin code?

currently i'm having a global init-routine which goes like $(".myPlugs_tGallery").tGallery();

i was thinking about some kind of dynamic jQuery statement like:
"apply plugincode to all divs which start with classname "myPlugins"

so there would be just one command for all my future plugins.

any ideas how to do it? thanks

Comment: Isn't it what you are doing?? Make a `livequery()` on `div.myPlugins` and attach your plugin

Answer (score 1):

Add an initialization block to your plugin .js file:

```
$(function() {
  $('div.myPlugs_gallery').tGallery();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with if statment

```
$('div:eq(.myPlugs_gallery)')
```